# DELETE request with parameters using Guzzle

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, guzzle, http-delete

I have to do a DELETE request, with parameters, in the CodeIgnitor platform. First, I tried using cURL, but I switched to Guzzle.

An example of the request in the console is:

```sh
curl -X DELETE -d '{"username":"test"}' http://example.net/resource/id
```

But in the documentation of Guzzle they use parameters just like GET, like `DELETE http://example.net/resource/id?username=test`, and I don't want to do that.

I tried with:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->request('DELETE', $url, $data);
```

but the request just calls `DELETE http://example.com/resource/id` without any parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I interpret your curl request properly, you are attempting to send json data as the body of your delete request.

```
// turn on debugging mode.  This will force guzzle to dump the request and response.
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['debug' => true,]);

// this option will also set the 'Content-Type' header.
$response = $client->delete($uri, [
    'json' => $data,
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

coming late on this question after having same.
Prefered solution, avoiding debug mode is to pass params in 'query' as :

```
$response = $client->request('DELETE', $uri, ['query' => $datas]);
```

$datas is an array
Guzzle V6

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    $response = json_decode($this->client->delete($uri,$params)->getStatusCode());        
    echo $response;
```

This will also give the status of the response as 204 or 404